# Column Shows 'id' Number Instead of Foreign Key Attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

When using the select2 field/column type in Laravel Backpack, the list view displays the 'id' of the foreign entity instead of the foreign key required (in this case the 'name' of the Session).

Laravel 5.8.4, Backpack 3.4.  I asked in GitHub and the response was that my relationships were incorrect in my models.  I don't think that's the problem as the name loads in the edit view.

**GradeCrudController**

```php
        $this->crud->addColumn([
            'label' => "Session",
            'type' => 'select2',
            'name' => 'session_id', // the db column for the foreign key
            'entity' => 'session', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'model' => "App\Models\Session" // foreign key model
        ]);
```

**Grade (Model)**

```php
    public function session()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Session');
    }
```

**Session (Model)**

```php
    public function grades()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Grade');
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it's been a few days and nobody has responded, I thought I'd post the answer I came up with.  Note that I highly doubt that this is the correct solution, but for my project it will do.

I added a [Laravel Observer](https://tutsforweb.com/laravel-model-observers-tutorial/) for the Grade Model. Once a user adds a new record, the observer visits the session table, pulls the name of the session using the key and adds it as a column to the Grades table.

Then in backpack I just display the 'name' column.

There has to be a better way than this... But for now it will do.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using a "select2" column type. That's not something Backpack provides by default - it only has a "select" column.

Most likely what happened is that Backpack loaded the "text" column, since it couldn't find a "select2" column. Hence, the ID.

Try changing "select2" to "select". It should work for you without any observers/anything else.

Comment: That's interesting.  What is this in the documentation?  Is this not a feature Backpack provides anymore? https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs/crud-fields#section-select2-1-n-relationship

Comment: Over here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-columns#select Notice this is a COLUMN type. You've linked to a FIELD type above. Fields and columns are different in Backpack - columns are used inside the ListEntries operation, fields inside the Create and Update operations. Some fields&columns are named the same (ex: select), but some are not (ex: there is a select2 field, but no select2 column). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I could not get the foreign key attribute to show up no matter what. I finally got it working by doing to following.

Add the foreign key to the belongsTo method. It should be the name of the column in that model that has the ID that is associated with in the belongsTo model.

```php
public function session()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Session','name');
}
```

One other item that I suggest is to make sure all columns that have foreign keys are set to the same data types in the database.